# Android - How to refresh an activity

Tags: android, wait

I'm wondering how to refresh an activity. Not like restart it, but refresh it. What is happening is I have it so a button lights up, and after it is clicked it waits 5 seconds then resets the buttons and has another one light up, the only problem is the other buttons are not lighting up, as it stays stuck on the same button. I don't know if this is a problem with the code, or I'm not calling a refresh, etc. Any help is good! Thanks.

```
if(selected == target) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Good job!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
h.postDelayed(task, millisDelay);
```

then my task is this:

```
private Runnable task = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
      ResetButtons();
      int rnd = new Random().nextInt(buttons.length);
      i = rnd;
      buttons[i].getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
};
```

Comment: I do not understand much. But do you want to change color or background of buttons after certain action ?

Comment: Use runOnUiThread for refreshing the UI.

Comment: You can also use `View.invalidate()` to force the view to redraw itself.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi, yes. I want the user to push the correct button and then it will wait a few seconds then a different, random button will light up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onClick (View v){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

(OR)

This is what I do to reload the activity after changing returning from a preference change.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

   super.onResume();
   this.onCreate(null);
}
```

This essentially causes the activity to redraw itself.

Comment: How do I do this without restarting the entire activity? Just updating  the UI so it updates smoothly instead of the page getting closed and opened again?

Comment: the view.invalidate() only updates the button when it is pushed, i need it to be updating as i push it so it automatically changes a different color. I think I need to use ASync but I have no idea where to start on that.

Comment: restarting the activity lifecycle is not a good solution for trying to force a redraw of ui components