# How to refresh an activity in Android?

Tags: android

I'm learning android app development by creating a **Wordle** like app. I'm currently testing if I can change the custom view **Letter's** properties by using a button named **Set** which calls the **testSet** method in MainActivity. The problem is the properties of the views do get changed but they don't get reflected in **main_activity**. I can't find a way to refresh the activity. I've tried the solutions to these questions

[Android - How to refresh an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324420/android-how-to-refresh-an-activity)

[Programmatically relaunch/recreate an activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486934/programmatically-relaunch-recreate-an-activity/7858127#7858127)

But none of them worked for me.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.wordlepromax;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String letter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.attempt1);
        Letter currView = (Letter) layout.getChildAt(0);
        if (letter != null) {
            currView.setLetter(letter);
        }
    }

    public void testSet(View view) {
        letter = "N";
        recreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        letter = savedInstanceState.getString("view_Letter");
    }

    // invoked when the activity may be temporarily destroyed, save the instance state here
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
        outState.putString("view_Letter", letter);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

main_activity.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/attempt1"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.483"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.example.wordlepromax.Letter
            android:id="@+id/letter10"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/letter11"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.example.wordlepromax.Letter
            android:id="@+id/letter11"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/letter12"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/letter10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.example.wordlepromax.Letter
            android:id="@+id/letter12"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/letter13"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.example.wordlepromax.Letter
            android:id="@+id/letter13"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/letter14"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.example.wordlepromax.Letter
            android:id="@+id/letter14"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:hint="@string/set_letter_test"
        android:onClick="testSet"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/attempt1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**
I was going through my old questions here and found this silly question I asked when I first started android app development and just wanted to update that both Vanilil and a_local_nobody are right all you have to do is change the attributes of a view and it'll change the appearance itself.

Comment: Why not just use  `Letter currView = (Letter) layout.getChildAt(0);
        if (letter != null) {
            currView.setLetter(letter);
        }` in `testSet` function instead of trying to recreate the activity ?

Comment: `I can't find a way to refresh the activity.` for a good reason, that's not how android development really works, stuff very rarely gets recreated

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc for `onRestoreInstanceState` :

> This method is called after onStart when the activity is being
> re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in
> savedInstanceState. Most implementations will simply use onCreate to
> restore their state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it here
> after all of the initialization has been done or to allow subclasses
> to decide whether to use your default implementation. The default
> implementation of this method performs a restore of any view state
> that had previously been frozen by onSaveInstanceState.

In your case it does not work, because you're setting `letter` variable to `View` inside of `onCreate` method, at this point `onRestoreInstanceState` just was not called and `letter` variable was not updated(restored).

Move this line to the begining of `onCreate` method. In this case you can remove `onRestoreInstanceState`.

```
letter = savedInstanceState.getString("view_Letter");
```